# How to avoid this empty row using QUERY() in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique, google-query-language

I've tried applying some criteria, but the row is still there.

This first empty row shouldn't be there.

Here is the formula, in case you'd like to help me correct it:
`=if(I4<>"", { IFERROR(query(Datasets!X3:AU,"select AS, AT, AJ, AR where AS matches date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(I4),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0),{"","","",""}); IFERROR(query(Datasets!BC3:BT,"select BC, BD, BS, BQ where BC matches date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(I4),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0),{"","","",""}) }, UNIQUE({query(Datasets!X3:AU,"select AS, AT, ' ', SUM(AR) where AS is not null group by AS, AT, ' ' label ' '' ', SUM(AR) '  '",0); query(Datasets!BC3:BT,"select BC, BD, ' ', SUM(BQ) where BC is not null group by BC, BD, ' ' label ' '' ', SUM(BQ) '  '",0) }))`
[image]

Comment: remove the spaces in the labels. `label x ' '` -> `label x ''` or use `query(formula,"offset 1",0)`

Comment: I'll try that, @ztiaa! Thanks for your comment and congrats on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(I4<>"", {IFERROR(QUERY(Datasets!X3:AU, 
 "select AS,AT,AJ,AR 
  where AS matches date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(I4), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", ), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(QUERY(Datasets!BC3:BT, 
 "select BC,BD,BS,BQ 
  where BC matches date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(I4), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", ), {"","","",""})}, 
 UNIQUE({QUERY(Datasets!X3:AU,
 "select AS,AT,' ',SUM(AR) 
  where AS is not null 
  group by AS,AT,' '
  label' ''',SUM(AR)''", ); 
 QUERY(Datasets!BC3:BT, 
 "select BC,BD,' ',SUM(BQ) 
  where BC is not null 
  group by BC,BD,' ' 
  label' ''',SUM(BQ)''", )}))
```

Comment: That actually didn't solve it. Couldnt see what changed in the formula... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i've wrapped the `QUERY()'s` in a new `QUERY()` and it worked. Thanks a lot!